# Including some values and excluding others from a field

Tags: mysql

The table can have more than one entry for a member - i.e. he can be a member of several groups. I wish to include members of all those groups commencing 'cr' but excluding from the list those who are also members of prodcr, But it does not work - it includes all those who are members of prodcr. I have spent many hours on this - please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
select DISTINCT mem_no
              , first_name
              , last_name
              , inits
              , addr1
              , post_code
              , email 
           FROM members m
           JOIN `group` g
          USING (mem_no) 
          WHERE ( 
                  NOT ('group' = "prodcr") 
            AND    (`group` LIKE "cr%")
                ) 
            ORDER 
               BY last_name ASC
                , first_name ASC 
            LIMIT 0,500
```

Comment: show the structure of both tables. What is the key/foreign key in both tables ?

Comment: Additionnaly... if you have  members and groups, the most logical way to handle this would be to have a group_member many-to-many relationship table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mem_no, first_name, last_name, inits, addr1,post_code, email 
       FROM members JOIN group USING (mem_no)
       WHERE group LIKE "cr%" AND  group != "prodcr"
       ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC 
       LIMIT 500
```

PS: it would be better if you name your table `group` and you column `group` something else ([group is a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)).

Comment: I had changed the actual label to group for explanation purposes - it is club in the sql. I had tried club <> "prodcr" and that didn't work either.

Comment: give me an example you get after executing this query but you dont want to get it as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading up every site I could lay my hands on and it would seem that this is the solution:

I have set it out below in case it helps anyone else with a similar predicament

SELECT mem_no, first_name, last_name, inits, addr1, post_code, email FROM members JOIN club USING (mem_no) WHERE club <> 'prodcr' AND club LIKE 'cr%' AND mem_no NOT IN (SELECT mem_no FROM club WHERE club = 'prodcr') GROUP BY mem_no ORDER by last_name ASC, first_name ASC limit 0,500

Comment: sorry but your query make no sense it is redundant, that will take more execution time for nothing.